# Fflutter application getting 16.5 MB of Counter application how to reduce below 6 MB in Flutter only for all Android device?

Tags: flutter, performance, android-studio, apk, flutter-dependencies

[Image that shows my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSDpw.png) [Second image that shows my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjbGG.png)
Please help me because.
If we are developing starting flutter application then getting :

```
  FLUTTER : - 16.5 Mb   (PLEASE REDUCE BELOW 6 MB )

  AND Android Getting 4.3 MB  WHICH BEST AS OF NOW
```

PLEASE SOLVE THIS :

```
flutter application getting 16.5 MB of Counter application how to reduce below 6 MB in flutter only for all android device ? THROUGH COMMANDLINE FLUTTER ANDROID STUDIO
```

GIVE ME THE SOLUTIONS

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#build-an-apk

Comment: what you got is a fat-apk.

use the command `flutter build apk --split-per-abi` to get slim variants